# Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations defined class generic still getting error?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I have MYDemoClass.cs

```
 [Serializable]
    public class MYDemoClass<T> where T : class
    {
```

Now in interface `IMyTask` I create method like following

```
 public interface IMyTask
    {
MYDemoClass<object> Update(int Id, MYDemoClass<T> data) where T : class;
}
```

in `MyTaskClass.cs`

```
 public MYDemoClass<object> Update(int Id, MYDemoClass<T> data) where T : class
        {
```

> which gives me build error `Constraints are not allowed on non-generic
>   declarations` why so? If I have already declare `MYDemoClass<T> where
>   T : class`?

Comment: Your method isn't generic - `T` doesn't exist as a type parameter, as you haven't introduced it as a type parameter...

Comment: `class MYDemoClass<T> where T : class` is a generic class. it has nothing to do with generic methods. you have to create a generic method too. you cant have `MYDemoClass<T>` inside non generic. in non generic method you can do `MYDemoClass<int>` or use some known types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to declare like this:

```
MYDemoClass<object> Update<T>(int Id, MYDemoClass<T> data) where T : class;
```

Comment: thanks but why needed `Update<T>` can you elaborate or give me link ? thanks

Comment: Generics need a Type Parameter. "T" in this case. This is how generics are declared.